# Why JavaScript URL form is not working nor redirecting?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am making a service in PHP where it creates a folder with a name typed into the input field.

I have tried to cobble together a little JavaScript to make the page redirects to the folder you just created(and the file called toggle.php)
here is my JavaScript:

```html
<?php 
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) {
  $dir = opendir($src); 
  @mkdir($dst); 
  while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
      if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
         if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
             recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
         } 
         else { 
             copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
         } 
      } 
  } 
 closedir($dir); 
}
 
$src = "./xe7";
 

$dst = $_POST['foldername']; 
 
recurse_copy($src,$dst);
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<div>
<body onload="timer=setTimeout('removeControls();',3)">
<h1>Drawblog</h1>
<div class="FAQ" style ="box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0);">
    <a href="#hide1" class="hide" id="hide1">Control panel</a>
    <a href="#show1" class="show" id="show1">-</a>
        <div class="list" style ="box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0);">
<form method="post" >
<input type="text" name="foldername" id ="togl">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id = "sm2" value="Create panorama" onclick ="newDoc();">

  
   <script type="text/javascript">
function newDoc() {
  var folder = document.getElementById("togl").value;
  var url = "http://hokuco.com/test/" + folder + "/toggle.php";
    window.location.assign(url)
};
    </script>
 </form>
<h3>Or,</h3>
<h2>Login with an access code(the account you just typed into the box above, or a code someone shared with you)</h2>
    <input type="text" id="field" />
    <button id="submit">Go</button>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var folder = document.getElementById("field").value;
  var url = "http://hokuco.com/test/" + folder + "/index.html";

  window.location.href = url;
});
    </script>
         </div>
</div>
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<p>make shocking panoramas in minutes, no account needed</p>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<p>special thanks to:</p>
  <div id="info"><a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js css3d</a> - panorama.</div>

 <h5>a hokuco company</h5>
</div>
<style>
.FAQ { 
    vertical-align: top; 
    height:auto !important; 
}
.list {
    display:none; 
    height:auto;
    margin:0;
    float: left;
}
.show {
    display: none; 
}
.hide:target + .show {
    display: inline; 
}
.hide:target {
    display: none; 
}
.hide:target ~ .list {
    display:inline; 
}

/*style the (+) and (-) */
.hide, .show {
 width: 45px;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #000;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #666;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #ffffff;
 opacity: .95;
  border-bottom: thick solid #000000;
 margin-right: 0;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.hide:hover, .show:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 opacity: 1;
   color: #000;
  background: #ffffff;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.list p{
    height:auto;
    margin:0;
}
.question {
 float: left;
 height: auto;
 width: 90%;
 line-height: 20px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: How can you redirect to a folder that you still have to create?

Comment: thank you i made such a stupid mistake, sometimes I think im doin jquery when im doin js

Comment: thats strange... it dosent work with php here ill post whole thing...

Comment: It's good that you provided more info, but you should really pare it down to only that which is needed to demonstrate the issue. Make your example code complete but lean.

Comment: maybe php is blocking the js...

Comment: now the php is broken...

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form">
<input type="text" id="mysearch-text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function () {
        var filmName = document.getElementById("mysearch-text").value;
        alert(filmName);
        if (filmName == "parker") window.location.href = "http://www.w3fools.com";
        else alert("hello");
        return false; //prevent the default behavior of the submit event
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain why the questions code didn't work, and how this code solves it.